# Using SfApexDoc with IntelliJ IDEA and Illuminated Cloud 2

Tags: illuminatedcloud, intellij

I'm wanting to generate API documentation using SfApexDoc with the "global" scope. However, I can't get it to work. I'm using a Windows 10 PC. What I've done:

1. Downloaded the JAR using the link on the [GitLab wiki for SfApexDoc](https://gitlab.com/StevenWCox/sfapexdoc/-/wikis/home)
2. Set up an external tool:
   [image]

Executing this external tool does something (just what, I don't know) since it takes a while to terminate, but the output folder remains stubbornly empty. The external tool console log shows nothing at all.

When I run the generated command in a Command window (with an update to specify the full path to the java app) and adding "-d" for debug I do get some output, like:

```
SfApexDoc version 1.3.0

Class: AchievementController.barInfo
  properties: achType finalGoal highLimit lowLimit starTitle width
  methods: barInfo
Class: AchievementController
  properties: AchType finalGoal highLimit lowLimit numberProgress starTitle width
  methods: AchievementController ...
```

later followed by more output like:

```
parseProjectDetail():
parseHtmlFile():
Processing: createshiftdemandsforjoborders
Processing: client_shifts
Processing: dynamicsearchselectcontroller
Processing: shiftschedulingcontroller2_test
...
```

But even then the output folder remains empty.

Anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A little late to this, but it works for me. The only difference on my end is that I'm specifying my full path for my source directory `-s C:\Users\Kris\IdeaProjects\ProductionDX\force-app\main\default\classes`

Comment: Thanks Kris. I added an answer about how this issue went away with a re-built Windows 10 install with all the gubbins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to move to a new PC and re-installed everything there. This actually solved the issue and I don't really know why. Regardless, the following combination works:

1. The SfApexDoc 1.3.0 JAR downloaded from the [SfApexDoc GitLap project wiki home page](https://gitlab.com/StevenWCox/sfapexdoc/-/wikis/Home)
2. OpenJDK 14 downloaded from the [OpenJDK site](https://jdk.java.net/)
3. IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)
4. Illuminated Cloud 2 (version 2.1.2.4)

This runs happily on Windows 10.