# Tool to extract custom objects including field names, descriptions and types into documentation?

Tags: metadata-api, documentation, data-model

I want to create HTML documentation pages [like this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) for 50+ custom objects containing 1000+ fields.

I'm aware that there are APIs for this information and that I could write my own tool (and [did so once](https://code.google.com/archive/p/force-metadata-jdbc-driver/)). But I'm hoping for a pointer to an open source tool for this purpose that someone has already written... Nothing obvious came up via Google.

Comment: Judging by your reputation and amount of badges, you probably have a lot of experience, so you are probably doing this for a good reason. Nevertheless, I have to ask: who is going to read/consult that generated documentation? Ever since the Agile manifesto, I don't do this kind of stuff anymore: just go to Salesforce and check it out yourself. Documentation is usually outdated 1 minute after generation.

Comment: Yeah fair points @SanderdeJong. The context here is in part a box ticking exercise so as to be able to say "yes" to the question "is your data model fully documented"; will be our custom objects not the SF ones.

Comment: [ApexDoc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303652/using-sfapexdoc-with-intellij-idea-and-illuminated-cloud-2) is the only OSS one we know about. You're better off with a commercial solution, there are some Q&As on here that mention various products.